# Regex: get number formated n.n.n from string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I am trying to get number i.e. 1.0.3 from string . I only want numbers that are formatted with two dots and have ver# before them.  Is my regex implementation correct. It is work but will it fail in any condition?

```
var str = "https://example.x.y.com/z/ver#1.5.0"; 
var res = str.match(/ver#.\.(?:(\d+)\.)?(?:(\d+)\.)?(\*|\d+)/g);
return res;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tthfkzjt/

Comment: Suggest you take a look here - https://regex101.com/r/vJ4qU1/1

Comment: I guess even a simpler regex like this `#\d+\.\d+.\d+` will be suffice. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bQ6kW7/1)

Comment: As @noob posted - https://regex101.com/r/vJ4qU1/2. That one will not match `ver#a.0.5` whereas your original one does match `ver#a.0.5`. You are probably better off using theirs.

Comment: @JosephGarrone. it's

Comment: Thanks everyone for sharing the information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to get number i.e. 1.0.3 from string . I only want numbers that are formatted with two dots and have `ver#` before them

This could be done by simple regex: `/ver#(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/`

Capture the first group using `\1` or `$1`.

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bQ6kW7/3)**</kbd>

<kbd>**[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h1132na1/1)**</kbd>

```js
var str = "https://example.x.y.com/z/ver#1.5.0"; 
var res = str.match(/ver#(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/);
document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = res ? res[1] : "";
```

```html
<div id="res"/>
```

Comment: Second dot should be escaped so it matches dot literally instead of matching any character. /ver#(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/. @noob can you edit it. Thanks!

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew: How did we missed this obvious thing ? Was there any reason not to escape second dot ?

Comment: If there is more than one issue in a solution, the possibility of overlooking one of them is very high. In this case, I was not focused on the expression itself, just on the JS code: I just blindly copied the pattern to jsfiddle.net from regex101.com and pasted  here.

Comment: @bitecoder: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. Appreciate it !